# Does local Clifford equivalence have a direct graphical representation for qudit graph states of non-prime dimension?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-state, graph-states

This question is a follow-up to the previous QCSE question: "[Are qudit graph states well-defined for non-prime dimension?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/are-qudit-graph-states-well-defined-for-non-prime-dimension)". From the question's answer, it appears that there is nothing wrong in *defining* graph states using $d$-dimensional qudits, however, it seems that other definitional aspects of graph-states do not similarly extend to non-prime dimension.

Specifically, for qubit graph states, one key aspect to their prevalence and use is the fact that: *any two graph states are local Clifford equivalent if and only if there is some sequence of local complementations that takes one graph to the other* (for simple, undirected graphs). Needless to say, this is an incredibly useful tool in analyses of quantum error correction, entanglement and network architectures.

When considering $n$-qudit graph states, the equivalent graph is now weighted with adjacency matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{n \times n}$, where $A_{ij}$ is the weight of edge $(i,j)$ (with $A_{ij}=0$ indicating no edge exists).
In the qudit case, [it was shown](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0610267.pdf) that LC equivalence can similarly be extended by the generalisation of local complementation ($\ast_a v$) and inclusion of an edge multiplication operation ($\circ_b v$), where:
\begin{align}
\ast_a v &: A_{ij} \mapsto A_{ij} + aA_{vi}A_{vj} \quad \forall\;\; i,j \in N_G(v), \;i \neq j \\
\circ_b v &: A_{vi} \mapsto bA_{vi} \quad\forall\;\; i \in N_G(v),
\end{align}
where $a, b = 1, \ldots, d-1$ and all arithmetic is performed modulo $p$.

Graphically, this is represented by the following operations (reproduced from [Ref. 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0610267.pdf)):
[image]

However, if the graph state is defined on qudits of non-prime dimension, then we can see these operations (seem to) fail to represent LC-equivalence.

For example, take the qudit state $|G\rangle$ depicted the graph $G$ in Fig. 1, defined for qudit dimension $d=4$, and let $x=y=z=2$, such that $A_{12}=A_{13}=A_{14}=2$.
In this case performing $\circ_2 1$ then $A_{1i} \mapsto 2 \times 2 = 4 \equiv 0 \bmod 4 \;\forall\; i$, and hence qudit $1$ is disentangled from all other qudits using only local operations.
Clearly this is wrong and occurs because of the problem of zero divisors as mentioned in the previous questions' [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2546/391).

My question is: **is there *any* set of graph operations that properly represent local Clifford equivalence for qudit graph states of non-prime dimension?**

**Note:** I am primarily interested in operations that **directly** apply to a state's representation as a single weighted graph, rather than possible decompositions into multiple prime-dimensional graph states, as suggested in Sec. 4.3 of "[Absolutely Maximally Entangled Qudit Graph States](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2879.pdf)".

Comment: Since you created the new tag [tag:graph-states], could you please write the tag wiki for it? Go [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/224). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect to use modulo arithmetic in this context. Instead finite field arithmetic should be applied. In $\textrm{GF}(4) = \{0, 1, x, x^2\}$ where $x^2 = x + 1$ and conjugation of $a$ is defined as $\bar{a} = a^2$.

Addition, multiplication and conjugation tables are then as follows:

[image]

In this picture we have $0 \equiv 0$, $1 \equiv 1$, $2 \equiv x$, and $3 \equiv x^2$ such that $2 \times 2 = 3$ and so the apparent inconsistency does not occur.

Comment: What definition of "2" are you using here? Absent any other convention for $\mathbb F = GF(4)$, I would presume $2 := 1_{\mathbb F} + 1_{\mathbb F} = 0_{\mathbb F} =: 0$,  in which case $2\times 2 = 0$.

Comment: I have added a clarifying edit :)